# Copied .minecraft folder onto new computer, now broken

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

<strike>I have a new laptop- rather than installing my bajillions of mods onto it I just copied and pasted my .minecraft folder. It works fine on my old laptop, but won't work on my new one-- I press play and the launcher closes, then nothing happens. The task manager shows javaw.exe appearing for a couple seconds and then suddenly dissappearing. Minecraft works fine with any other version besides forge. I'm running forge 1.6.4. Any help?</strike>

Note: both computers are running Windows 8.

Okay, so I just discovered something important. Rather than copying my minecraft.jar, I simply installed forge- and yet the same error happens with no mods installed. Here's the error report:

```
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Forge Mod Loader version 6.4.49.965 for Minecraft 1.6.4 loading
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Java is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_25, running on Windows 8.1:amd64:6.3, installed at C:\Users\Kenemon\Desktop\runtime\jre-x64\1.8.0_25
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [FINE] [ForgeModLoader] Java classpath at launch is C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\minecraftforge\9.11.1.965\minecraftforge-9.11.1.965.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.8\launchwrapper-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-all\4.1\asm-all-4.1.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.10.2\scala-library-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.10.2\scala-compiler-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\lzma\lzma\0.0.1\lzma-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\argo\argo\2.25_fixed\argo-2.25_fixed.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.47\bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\14.0\guava-14.0.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.2\gson-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.0\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.0\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965.jar
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [FINE] [ForgeModLoader] Java library path at launch is C:\Users\Kenemon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965-natives-121023374937945
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [FINE] [ForgeModLoader] Enabling runtime deobfuscation
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [FINE] [ForgeModLoader] Instantiating coremod class FMLCorePlugin
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [FINE] [ForgeModLoader] Enqueued coremod FMLCorePlugin
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [FINE] [ForgeModLoader] Instantiating coremod class FMLForgePlugin
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [FINE] [ForgeModLoader] Enqueued coremod FMLForgePlugin
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [FINE] [ForgeModLoader] All fundamental core mods are successfully located
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [FINE] [ForgeModLoader] Discovering coremods
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
2014-12-28 10:00:01 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
2014-12-28 10:00:02 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
2014-12-28 10:00:02 [SEVERE] [ForgeModLoader] Unable to launch
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:865)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:114)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)
```

Comment: Is the same java version as on the old system installed?

Comment: Yeah, just checked and the versions are the same.

Comment: I guess you better copy saves and mods folder only after reinstalling minecraft and forge

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open, because there already is an answer to this question. I doubt that it would be a good idea to close all questions about technical problems in modded versions of minecraft, and minecraft only. I understand that some may disagree with me (there seems to be a lot of debate in meta). If you feel like this is reason enough to close it, then feel free to vote accordingly.

Comment: @bearb001 The community [has clearly decided](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no/10391#10391) that modded minecraft crashing is off-topic. Meta consensuses that certain questions are off-topic apply to all posts, regardless of their age, regardless of whether they were answered or not. (Disclosure: I am the user who flagged the post for closure)

Comment: Despite there already being an answer, I'm afraid that off-topic questions are still off-topic.

Comment: @bearb001 Questions must stand on their own. Voting to leave open because you disagree with the blanket ban on modded Minecraft tech support is your prerogative, but you should not be voting to leave open just because there's an answer.

Comment: @Schism People want that minecraft tech support questions are off-topic, because it's usually hard, or impossible to find the solution. If there already is an answer, then that reason is not valid, the question is clearly not unsolvable and someone has put time and effort into solving it. I would be ok with making all questions for tech support for modded games off-topic, but making a rule for one game, and one game only, is wrong. I did explain myself poorly in my last comment, I would still not vote to close a question, just because it's about a particular game, even if nobody had answered.

Comment: @bearb001 We tried allowing modded minecraft tech support questions to be on-topic a while back, and it was a disaster. Compared to any other "modded game support" question, it was easily 1000 to 1 for modded minecraft, and there are always so many possibilities of issues with mods and relatively custom configurations they were near impossible to troubleshoot. There is plenty of history there, and the decision was discussed in great detail for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your culprit:

```
2014-12-28 10:00:02 [SEVERE] [ForgeModLoader] Unable to launch
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:865)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:114)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)
```

A change introduced in Java 8u20 has been giving Forge trouble.  This was recently fixed in Forge, so updating Forge will solve this for you.

If you have mods that depend on older versions of Forge, however, you'll have to get a bit dirty.  There are two known ways around the issue:

1. **Patch your local Forge version.**  FyberOptic on minecraftforum.net has [files and instructions on how to do this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2206446-forge-1-6-4-1-7-2-java-8-compatibility-patch).  In short, you take a patched version of the offending code, plug it into your local library, and that should take care of it.
2. **Install Java 7.**  You can keep several Java installations on the same machine.  See "[Minecraft Forge 1.7.10 will not start](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182269/minecraft-forge-1-7-10-will-not-start?rq=1)" for instructions on how to run Forge on the old Java.

   Word of warning, though: official support for Java 7 will be [discontinued after April 2015](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html).